# Gitlab-runner won't start service on macOS

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I’ve successfully installed GitLab Runner on macOS Darwin arm64, and everything works like a charm when I use `gitlab-runner run`. However, I’m encountering an issue when trying to start it as a service with `gitlab-runner start`. The error message I’m getting is “FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: exit status 134,” and unfortunately, no log files are being generated.

I’ve checked permissions and looked into compatibility issues, but the problem persists. Are there any specific configurations or requirements for running GitLab Runner as a service on macOS arm64 that I might be missing?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is resolved.**

When you face this issue, do this steps.

1. uninstall gitlab-runner service with this command `gitlab-runner uninstall`
2. remove your `gitlab-runner.plist` service file from your `$USERNAME/Library/LaunchAgents/` location
3. remove your `config.toml` file
4. `su {YOUR_USERNAME}`
5. and run this command  `sudo gitlab-runner  install --user {your_username}`
6. register the runner `sudo gitlab-runner register`

Thanks Arman jan for providing this resolution!